# Present Value with annual effective interest question about theory

Tags: homework

Say Brian is saving up for college by placing 600$ at the end of every month into an account earning 4% annual effective interest.  Calculate the present value of these payments if he deposits money in this way for 8 years.

Doing it via formulas you get ...

i^12 = 12((1.04)^(1/12)-1) = .03928

PV = 7200 * (1-(1.04)^(-8))/.03928 = 49364.32

however how would you do this by hand? What I mean is, adding each monthly payment, adding interest etc by hand.. I tried it but it didn't work, can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: How often is the interest in the account compounded?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math problem/homework assignment, not of general PF interest.

Comment: Look here: [Calculating The Present And Future Value Of Annuities](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/03/101503.asp).  For your questing on saving see the section titled, *Calculating the Present Value of an Annuity Due*.  The example mentions rent payments but it's exactly the same present-value calculation as for savings deposit payments.

Comment: I agree that it's a homework assignment or should be, and probably duplicates past answers as well... I answered because I had spare time while waiting for a test to complet.

Answer (score 1):

Interest per month is 12th root of annual interest, or a multiplier of about 1.0327%.

At end of 1st month, you start with $0, add interest on $0, and add $600, getting $600.

2nd month: start with $600, add 0.0327% interest plus $600, getting $1219.62.

3rd: balance plus interest plus deposit yields $1859.50

Repeat ad nauseam. Easier with a spreadsheet or a bit of trivial programming. Or you can try to re-derive the formulas, but that is left as an exercise for the student.